# in a few conditions, compare row with a previous row and drop rows with condition in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a concept of what I need to do, but I can't write the right code to run, please take a look and give some advice.

step 1. find the rows that contains values in the second column

step 2. with those rows, compare the value in the first column with their previous row

step 3. drop the rows with larger first column value

```
|missing | diff |
|--------|------|
| 0      | nan  |
| 1      | 60   |
| 1      | nan  |
| 0      | nan  |
| 0      | nan  |
| 1      | 180  |
| 1      | nan  |
| 0      | 120  |
```

eg. I want to compare the missing values with the rows values in diff [120,180,60] and their previous rows. in the end, the desire dataframe will look like

```
|missing | diff |
|--------|------|
| 0      | nan  |
| 1      | nan  |
| 0      | nan  |
| 0      | nan  |
| 0      | 120  |
```

update question according to the answer, got the same df as original df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data={'missing':[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],'diff':[np.nan,60,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,180,np.nan,120]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
missing diff
0   0   NaN
1   1   60.0
2   1   NaN
3   0   NaN
4   0   NaN
5   1   180.0
6   1   NaN
7   0   120.0
```

```
if df['diff'][ind]!=np.nan:
    if ind!=0:
        if df['missing'][ind]>df['missing'][ind-1]:
            df=df.drop(ind,0)
        else:
            df=df.drop(ind-1,0)
df
```

```
missing diff
0   0   NaN
1   1   60.0
2   1   NaN
3   0   NaN
4   0   NaN
5   1   180.0
6   1   NaN
7   0   120.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for sure:

```
for ind in df.index:
    if np.isnan(df['diff'][ind])==False:
        if ind!=0:
            if df['missing'][ind]>df['missing'][ind-1]:
                df=df.drop(ind,0)
            else:
                df=df.drop(ind-1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
m = df['diff'].notna()
df = (
    pd.concat([
        df[df['diff'].isna()],
        df[m][df[m.shift(-1).fillna(False)]['missing'].values >
              df[m]['missing'].values]
    ])
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  missing  diff
1       0  <NA>
3       1  <NA>
4       0  <NA>
5       0  <NA>
7       1  <NA>
8       0   120
```

Comment: but for the row with index 7, it should be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd #import pandas

#define dictionary

data={'missing':[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],'diff':[nan,60,nan,nan,nan,180,nan,120]}

#dictionary to dataframe

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

#for each row in dataframe

for ind in df.index:

```
if df['diff'][ind]!="nan":
  if ind!=0:

        #only each row whose diff value is a number

        #find the rows that contains values in the second column and compare it with previous value

    if df['missing'][ind]>df['missing'][ind-1]:

                #drop the rows with larger first column value

        df=df.drop(ind,0)

    else:

        df=df.drop(ind-1,0)
```

print(df)

Comment: I got a key error on row ifdf['missing'][ind]>df['missing'][(ind-1)]:  and get KeyError: -1

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    354                 try:
--> 355                     return self._range.index(new_key)
    356                 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: -1 is not in range

Comment: yes, it was a mistake from my side. check the edited or new post for the correct code. its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This will work

for ind in df.index:

```
if df['diff'][ind]!="nan":
    if ind!=0:
        if df['missing'][ind]>df['missing'][ind-1]:
            df=df.drop(ind,0)
        else:
            df=df.drop(ind-1,0)
```

Comment: code seems good, but I got the same result dataframe as the original one, donno what's wrong

Comment: also check spelling and case of your nan value in both conditions and defined dictionary.